Based on STM32F401 and uC/OS, a hard fault occurred, and the PSP pointed to an incorrect address (0x08019a88 flash)
I am writing the attitude estimation code for my drone, so I included the Eigen library to handle matrix operations. During debugging, I found that my program entered a hard fault while performing matrix operations with the Eigen library.
It shows that I enter a hard fault when reaching this line.
K_ = dh * P_next * dh_trans;

K_  is defined as
Eigen::Matrix<float, 9, 9> K_ {....}

dh is defined as
 Eigen::Matrix<float, 9, 7> dh {....}

dh_trans is defined as
Eigen::Matrix<float, 7, 9> dh_trans = dh.transpose();

When the hard fault occurs, my LR data is 0xFFFFFFED and the PSP is 0x08019a88. In the STM32F401, this address is in the flash memory (0x8000 0000 - 0x0807 FFFF), and in my understanding, the PSP should not point to flash.
I dont know what make this happen,thanks for helping me!
Here are more info:
The CFSR(Configurable fault status register) is 0x00000001.The manual for this section is as follows:CFSR MMFSR

Are you using an OS or running on bare-metal? Is your stack big enough for all these matrices?

@pmacfarlane He is using RTOS which is something in between - basically a library providing task switching and synchronization.

The issue lies in my use of uC/OS. I called OSStatInit(), but if I call this function, I can only declare one task in main, and then declare other tasks within the first task. However, I have declared two tasks in main.

If this is your entering in hardfault, I think the PSP may not what is active in your code(instead the msp is), since the PC and some important message must be saved in stack before hardfault. First you can check the some special register:

To help detect what type of error was encountered in the fault
handler, the Cortex®-M3 and Cortex®-M4 processors also have a number
Fault Status Registers (FSRs) and Fault Address Registers (FARs) that
are used for fault analysis.​
(from stm32 blog)

And from your infos I guess that It may be because of some instructions that are not supported on cortexM4 as the memory consumption there seems not so expensive.(so you can go on check the special register above and improve you description)
